# How to write a linear regression with an expanding window in R (no packages)

Tags: r, for-loop, linear-regression, quantitative-finance

How do you set up a linear regression with an expanding window in R without using packages?

What is the best way to set up a for loop so that the regression is done first with 30 days of data, then 31 days, then 32, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is an example of how to set up an expanding window, here is one. It loops (`lapply`) from `start` to the length of vector `x`, the regressor fitting a linear model to the first `i` data points.

```
start <- 30
res <- lapply(start:n, function(i){
  k <- seq.int(i)
  fit <- lm(y[k] ~ x[k])
  c(days = i, coef(fit))
})
res <- do.call(rbind, res)

op <- par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(res[,1], res[,2], xlab = "window size", ylab = "Intercept", pch = 16)
plot(res[,1], res[,3], xlab = "window size", ylab = "beta", pch = 16)
par(op)
```

**Data creation code.**

```
set.seed(1234)

n <- 100
x <- jitter(seq.int(n))
y <- x + rnorm(n)
```